# I have some problems with xpath in python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I’m trying to get distinct values with xpath query and lxml module.
So my code seems to work fine but i have two problems which i can’t solve. 
Xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="osmconvert 0.8.5">
        <node id="429459476" lat="55.6091243" lon="37.7270414" version="2" timestamp="2012-02-20T18:13:50Z" changeset="10743203" uid="210173" user="osmmaker">
        <tag k="amenity" v="library"/>
        <tag k="name" v="Детская библиотека №101"/>
        <tag k="opening_hours" v="Mo-Fr 12:00-18:00; Sa 12:00-17:00"/>
        <tag k="phone" v="+7-495-3995297"/>
    </node>
    <node id="448176571" lat="55.6098905" lon="37.7317767" version="2" timestamp="2009-11-03T16:02:27Z" changeset="3025778" uid="75496" user="navigARTor">
        <tag k="highway" v="bus_stop"/>
        <tag k="name" v="Воронежская улица"/>
    </node>
    <node id="448176571" lat="55.6098905" lon="37.7317767" version="2" timestamp="2009-11-03T16:02:27Z" changeset="3025778" uid="75496" user="navigARTor">
        <tag k="highway" v="bus_stop"/>
        <tag k="name" v="Воронежская улица"/>
    </node>
</osm>
```

Python code

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('out.xml')
tags = tree.xpath('./node[tag[not(@k = preceding::tag/@k)]]')
with open('10.xml','w') as f:
    for tag in tags:
          f.write(etree.tostring(tag,pretty_print=True).decode())
```

Xml after xpath query

```
<node id="429459476" lat="55.6091243" lon="37.7270414" version="2" timestamp="2012-02-20T18:13:50Z" changeset="10743203" uid="210173" user="osmmaker">
        <tag k="amenity" v="library"/>
        <tag k="name" v="&#1044;&#1077;&#1090;&#1089;&#1082;&#1072;&#1103; &#1073;&#1080;&#1073;&#1083;&#1080;&#1086;&#1090;&#1077;&#1082;&#1072; &#8470;101"/>
        <tag k="opening_hours" v="Mo-Fr 12:00-18:00; Sa 12:00-17:00"/>
        <tag k="phone" v="+7-495-3995297"/>
    </node>


<node id="448176571" lat="55.6098905" lon="37.7317767" version="2" timestamp="2009-11-03T16:02:27Z" changeset="3025778" uid="75496" user="navigARTor">
        <tag k="highway" v="bus_stop"/>
        <tag k="name" v="&#1042;&#1086;&#1088;&#1086;&#1085;&#1077;&#1078;&#1089;&#1082;&#1072;&#1103; &#1091;&#1083;&#1080;&#1094;&#1072;"/>
    </node>
```

Problem #1

How to get full xml document like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="osmconvert 0.8.5">
        <node id="429459476" lat="55.6091243" lon="37.7270414" version="2" timestamp="2012-02-20T18:13:50Z" changeset="10743203" uid="210173" user="osmmaker">
        <tag k="amenity" v="library"/>
        <tag k="name" v="&#1044;&#1077;&#1090;&#1089;&#1082;&#1072;&#1103; &#1073;&#1080;&#1073;&#1083;&#1080;&#1086;&#1090;&#1077;&#1082;&#1072; &#8470;101"/>
        <tag k="opening_hours" v="Mo-Fr 12:00-18:00; Sa 12:00-17:00"/>
        <tag k="phone" v="+7-495-3995297"/>
    </node>
<node id="448176571" lat="55.6098905" lon="37.7317767" version="2" timestamp="2009-11-03T16:02:27Z" changeset="3025778" uid="75496" user="navigARTor">
        <tag k="highway" v="bus_stop"/>
        <tag k="name" v="&#1042;&#1086;&#1088;&#1086;&#1085;&#1077;&#1078;&#1089;&#1082;&#1072;&#1103; &#1091;&#1083;&#1080;&#1094;&#1072;"/>
    </node>
</osm>
```

Problem #2
And how to get rid from this abracadabra

```
v="&#1042;&#1086;&#1088;&#1086;&#1085;&#1077;&#1078;&#1089;&#1082;&#1072;&#1103; &#1091;&#1083;&#1080;&#1094;&#1072
```

P.S. Sorry for my bad english i hope you’ll understand

Comment: The abacadabra is your original Cyrillic text. Do you want to get rid of it (meaning: "remove it"), or do you want to see it as regular Cyrillic text? (If that is the case, there are standard solutions to do so. Look for "convert HTML entities to text".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider XPath's sibling [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) to manipulate your source XML. Whereas XPath is great for parsing select areas of a document, XSLT is a special-purpose language designed to transform documents. And specifically what you need is more the [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) where you index the document by an element/attribute value (using `xsl:key`) for grouping to return distinct values. Here we use `node/@id`.

Python's `lxml` module can process XSLT 1.0 scripts. Since such scripts are well-formed XML files, they can be parsed from file or as embedded string. One other reason to go this route is preserving unicode, the challenge of your original output, as the `etree.tostring()` method is rendering [character entities](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) for the special cyrillic characters.

**XSLT** Script *(save as .xsl)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="nodekey" match="node" use="@id" />

  <xsl:template match="/osm">   
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
     <xsl:for-each select="node[count(. | key('nodekey', @id))]">
      <xsl:copy>        
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*|*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Python** Script

```
from lxml import etree

xml = etree.parse('Input.xml')
xsl = etree.parse('XSLTScript.xsl')

transform = etree.XSLT(xsl)
newdom = transform(xml)

with open('Output.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(newdom)
```

**XML** Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="osmconvert 0.8.5">
  <node id="429459476" lat="55.6091243" lon="37.7270414" version="2" timestamp="2012-02-20T18:13:50Z" changeset="10743203" uid="210173" user="osmmaker">
    <tag k="amenity" v="library"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Детская библиотека №101"/>
    <tag k="opening_hours" v="Mo-Fr 12:00-18:00; Sa 12:00-17:00"/>
    <tag k="phone" v="+7-495-3995297"/>
  </node>
  <node id="448176571" lat="55.6098905" lon="37.7317767" version="2" timestamp="2009-11-03T16:02:27Z" changeset="3025778" uid="75496" user="navigARTor">
    <tag k="highway" v="bus_stop"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Воронежская улица"/>
  </node>
</osm>
```

Comment: I think that what exactly i'm looking for